# GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity Unknown COM Exception

Tags: c#, active-directory

When deploying this code to a web application where the identity is the app pool user the following code throws an unknown COM exception.  The exception is happening when the FindByIdentity method is invoked.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error
>   (0x8000500c)

```
using (PrincipalContext prinCon = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
     GroupPrincipal groupPrin = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(prinCon, name);
}
```

If I change the application pool identity to a domain user this problem is resolved.  Which initially leads me to believe it is a permission/security issue.  However, this error does not happen on all servers, just some.  Additionally, a restart will fix this issue.

So, my question is why would restarting the server fix this issue? And is there a way I make this work without restarting?

I've done a fair amount of googling and haven't come across anyone with the same problem, a few permission similar issues, but none that help solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `name` value?? What did you specify there??

Comment: It is the name of the group to search for, a string, for example "Administrators"

Comment: What is your app pool user account that you were using before you changed to use a domain user?  Was it a local user account?  
Can you please paste the app pool user account name here?  The `GroupPrincipal.FindbyIdentity` obviously needs to authenticate your app pool user account to Active Directory in order to do the LDAP query.

Comment: The identity is the ApplicationPoolIdentity user.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the app pool account is what worked for me.  It was ApplicationPoolIdentity user, but after I changed to Network Service, this error went away and the AD code works fine.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well, but I've been deploying this web app for over a year now without issue.  Suddenly I got this error without making any changes to this section of code.  I wonder if an update could be responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify an identity type, but then you're feeding it a string. Perhaps its not knowing how to search for the string. For example, maybe it is assuming the string is a guid and then attempting to parse it and then failing.

Try something like:

```
var groupPrin = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(prinCon, IdentityType.Name , name);
```

Also, try to set your PrincipalContext with some credentials that definitely have authority to perform these operations such as an admin or services account.